# Troubleshoot/ Tune Android performance / speed

Tags: performance

I have a Motorola Xoom (not rooted) and new to the Android world (at least as an advanced user).

I've installed several (around 30) games + several (around 30) apps. I've noticed that it became a lot more slow. Actually browsers can barely work (they hang from time to time). I noticed that several games and apps have active daemons running.

I wanted to:

- Track the apps that are being used.
- Track the apps that are loaded on startup (and eventually change it).
- Do anything to improve performance

**TL:DR;** I want to troubleshoot / tune my Android installation.

Is there any application for that?

Is there any document recommended for this? (I'm an advanced user - developer)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There are a bunch of Tutorials around on the net on how to increase performance of your Android device (e.g. on LifeHackers [here](http://lifehacker.com/5709148/how-to-speed-up-your-old-sluggish-android-device) and [here](http://lifehacker.com/5897770/how-to-speed-up-clean-up-and-revive-your-android-phone)). One thing to definitely keep your fingers *AWAY* from are so-called "boosters" and (automated) Task-Killers. As rm-vanda already stated, they make things only worse; tasks should only be killed if they misbehave (e.g. are hanging, running havoc while eating your CPU and the like). Android manages its RAM fine, no need to worry about that.

As for the auto-starters, I can recommend [AutoRun Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rs.autorun), which is actively maintained and simply the best of all I tried (and I tried a lot).

To figure out what is consuming your ressources, a good candidate helping you would be [System Tuner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ccc71.pmw). While the free version simply lets you monitor activity life, the pro-version also offers background-monitoring and stores its data for later analysis.

Some other steps you could perform include:

- from time to time, clean up caches (to remove old data and get back precious internal memory; helping apps in this segment include [Cache Clear](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.menue.cacheclear), [Quick Cache Cleaner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appswhere.cachecleaner), [CacheCleaner NG](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.lsartory.cachecleaner.ng), and [Android System Cleaner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tools.androidsystemcleaner) - the latter taking care for more things than just cache
- Moving some rarely used Apps to SD (if they don't have widgets you are using) saves additional internal space.
- uninstall unused apps

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you are an advanced user, I would recommend rooting your device.
The Tegra 2 is brick-proof, so you have nothing to fear. The [XDA forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com) can help you with rooting and whatnot.

But, if you have several apps that are simultaneously running services or processes, well, that's exactly your problem! I use [Fast Reboot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.greatbytes.fastreboot) to clean up excessive processes.

It is also noteable that TASK MANAGER APPLICATIONS can cause the sort of problem your talking about. As of Android 2.2+ task managers are obsolete - Android handles task management for you.

For managing startup applications, you can use [Startup Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=imoblife.startupmanager).

You can also see which applications are burning the most battery under your battery settings! This has helped me to find applications that are running rogue processes they shouldn't be running.

Comment: Android always handled task management. Also hot reboot is not too useful if you have tons of apps launching on boot.

Comment: It is different than a Hot Reboot. 
Fast reboot *kills* those apps that are starting on boot. 
So that's precisely what it is useful for.

Comment: So it's an auto killing task manager? Sorry but that's even worse...

Answer (score -1):

As already said by izzy, autoruns manager is the best. Just disable unwanted receivers.

Additionally, here are some others tips:

- say no to widgets
- install android firewall.
- disable internet access to unwanted apps